# Lock/Mutex Connection/Messages Using Boost Library

Tags: multithreading, boost, synchronization, locking, mutex

I'm trying to learn the lock/mutex stuff using boost library, but all that I found from the internet is too abstract or complicated.

Would you guys recommend me some tutorials, which are easy to understand?  Thanks.

I'm working on a project.  Server-Client architecture.

The server can receive messages from the client or send messages to client.  The server can also send messages using multiple threads.

I believe that I have to do thread synchronization to handle multiple threads for sending messages via the same connection, right?

Can you guys give me a simple pseudo code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip mutexes and threads, read about [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview.html) if you are designing a client server architecture. Particularly, study the asynchronous design that it promotes with concurrency without the explicit use of threads.

Comment: I understand I should use boost::asio for a fresh new project.  but I have a large amount of base code handling the Network Connection, so currently, I won't change everything to boost.  I just got a problem 1 minute ago, that two threads are sending messages at the same time via the same connection, and I got an inconsistent state in one of my flush()/send() function.

Comment: by the way, I used a mutex to guard the (msg->sendPacket and flush) block, and then it seems this issue disappeared.  I'm not sure if this is the correct solution to my current project for network connection.